# How do I use the ContinuousRectangleBorder's getOuterPath so it looks like an inverted circular border?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a SliverAppBar to which I'm trying to give a custom shape:

```
return SliverAppBar(
   shape: MyShapeBorder(10),
```

I've been playing around with the ContinuousRectableBorder:

```
class MyShapeBorder extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  const MyShapeBorder(this.curveHeight);
  final double curveHeight;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => Path()
    ..lineTo(0, rect.size.height)
    //Don't know what to put here, quadraticBezierTo? conicTo? ArcTo? and what would be the values?
    )
    //And then I assume a Line to and then another function?
    ..close();
}
```

but I can't seem to be able to figure it out. This is what I would like for it to look like:
[image]

Similar to what I have here:

[image]

But I was able to create this much more easily using:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10));
        ),
```

But I can't do this now because instead of wrapping the white bit in the container, I would like to provide a custom shape to the green bit (the SliverAppBar)

Comment: extend `ShapeBorder`, use `Path.fillType` property and `Path.addRect` and `Path.addRRect` methods to form the path you want

Comment: Hi I'll try the filltype and path.addRect and path.addRRect - that might be easier than trying to figure out the curve.

Comment: What didn't work @psking - I couldn't figure out how to actually draw the shape - as in the coordinates and paths or the shapes. Visual/spacial is an area I severely lack

Comment: you dont have to draw anything: all you need is to return a `Path` object from `getOuterPath()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
    class _BottomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width - 5, size.height - 20, size.width - 25, size.height - 20)
      ..lineTo(25, size.height - 20)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(5, size.height - 20, 0, size.height)
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Example Usgae:

```
class Curved extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;//pass any of ur widget here, it will be clipped
  const Curved({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(clipper: _BottomClipper(), child: child);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I took [Rajesh Jr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983745/6922631) comment and improved the code a little so that you modify the radius of the inverted corner and also choose if you want the only left, right, or both corners affected.

```
class InvertedBottomBorder extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  InvertedBottomBorder({
    this.left = true,
    this.right = true,
    this.radius = 40,
  })  : assert(left != null),
        assert(right != null),
        assert(radius != null);

  final bool left;

  final bool right;

  final double radius;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - (right ? 0 : radius))
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height - radius,
          size.width - radius, size.height - radius)
      ..lineTo(radius, size.height - radius)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height - radius, 0, size.height - (left ? 0 : radius))
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

In my app, I wanted only the left side affected so that I could achieve this seamless, rounded look:

[image]