# performance issue on Raster thread

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a class as image grid tile and after i am trying to add shape parameter to card it shows performance issue on Raster thread. After i remove shape from Card it works fine. Here's a snippet.

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:app/models/models.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/pages.dart';
import 'package:app/providers/providers.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/widgets.dart';

class ImageGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Items>? itemsList;
  final int index;
  const ImageGrid({
    Key? key,
    required this.itemsList,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double borderRadius = 50;
    return Hero(
        tag: itemsList!.elementAt(index).id,
        child: Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: index % 2 == 0 ? 8 : 2,
                right: index % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 8,
              ),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 4,
                shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 2 / 2,
                        child: Stack(
                          fit: StackFit.expand,
                          children: [
                            CachedNetworkImage(
                              progressIndicatorBuilder:
                                  (context, url, progress) => Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  value: progress.progress,
                                ),
                              ),
                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                  const Icon(Icons.error),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              memCacheHeight: 400,
                              imageUrl: itemsList!.elementAt(index).thumb!,
                            ),
                            Positioned.fill(
                              child: Material(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(11),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Card(
                                  elevation: 0,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                          borderRadius / 1.65 + 3)),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 60,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Flexible(
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                itemsList!
                                                    .elementAt(index)
                                                    .name!,
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                                  fontFamily: 'GoogleSans',
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                itemsList!
                                                    .elementAt(index)
                                                    .author!,
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 13.0,
                                                  fontFamily: 'GoogleSans',
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Consumer(
                                          builder: (context, ref, child) {
                                            var favManager =
                                                ref.watch(favProvider);
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              child: IconButton(
                                                icon: Icon(itemsList!
                                                        .elementAt(index)
                                                        .isFavorite
                                                    ? Icons.favorite
                                                    : Icons
                                                        .favorite_border_outlined),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  if (itemsList!
                                                      .elementAt(index)
                                                      .isFavorite) {
                                                    favManager.removeFromFav(
                                                      itemsList!
                                                          .elementAt(index),
                                                    );
                                                  } else {
                                                    favManager.addToFav(
                                                      itemsList!
                                                          .elementAt(index),
                                                    );
                                                  }
                                                  itemsList!
                                                          .elementAt(index)
                                                          .isFavorite =
                                                      !itemsList!
                                                          .elementAt(index)
                                                          .isFavorite;
                                                },
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          },
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )),
      
    );
  }
}
```

i am using a futurebuilder to fetch data from json and then show them in ListView.Builder. I have tried it in Profile mode.

Comment: try this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/61983745/11662604